# How can I update to the not yet officially released Ionic 1.2?

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic 1.2 has been announced:
http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-1-2/

The source code is availible here:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.2.0

But I haven't been able to install with with some shell commands that I have attempted:

```
$ bower install --save ionic#1.2.0
$ bower install https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz
$ bower install driftyco/ionic-bower#v1.2.0 --force
```

I can download the source code but don't know how to use it to update my ionic framework

Comment: I just realized that this is perhaps not a programming question. If so, is there any good place on StackExchange for these kinds of questions that are closely related to programming, but are not really programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it with bower using:

> $ **bower install ionic#1.2.0 --force**

Anyway, you should take into account that this will only download libraries and source code, but not a CLI tool.

So in my opinion, if you want to test ionic 1.2, you should

1. Create an ionic project (as usual)
2. Perform **bower install ionic#1.2.0 --force**, in order to get the new ionic libs
3. Replace in your project the content of **www/lib/ionic/** with the content of the recently downloaded **bower_components/ionic/release/**.

> DETAIL: Ionic uses to include a **.bowerrc file** that **causes bower packages to be placed in www/lib**, instead of inside bower_components, so maybe you'll simply need to replace the content of **www/lib/ionic/** with **www/lib/ionic/release** (**--force** is need because www/lib/ionic already exists).